# Update UI from any class without using events

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Most of my UserControls and classes need to be able to add entry (log) to ObservableCollection in MainWindow which is bound by a ListBox.

Is there an elegant way to do it without passing MainWindow to each of these classes and controls and without usage of events so I don't need to worry about memory leaks?

EDIT:
Good idea that I could pass only Log class but I would still like to avoid passing Log on instantiating to every class.

I am hoping for existence of some application wide listener that would be able to receive message from anywhere, keeping code clean.

Comment: what makes you think that there will be `Memory Leaks` are you writing code where you are not either implementing the `Auto Disposing of Objects i. using(){}` or not cleaning up objects yourself.. `You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged` if you are not familiar with how to do that then here is where you can start reading `Daniel` [INotifyPropertyChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: @DJKRAZE Not `-=`ing event handlers can pin otherwise properly disposed objects in the heap and prevent the GC from cleaning them up.  That's not to say that there isn't an easy solution to the problem (ie : removing handlers that you've added), but there are more ways to provoke a memory leak than you've suggested.

Comment: Why are you passing MainWindow?  Just pass the log.

Comment: `J` I am well aware of the many ways that Memory Leaks can be Introduced I was just asking in general

Comment: @DJKRAZE Fair enough, it just seemed that from OP's content their primary concern for risking memory leaks is the forgetting of event handler unsubscription...which you didn't mention.

Comment: very hard to determine and or mention the subscribing / unsubscribing to `Events` when there is no Obvious code sample but I respect your comment as a valid assumption as well..

Comment: The only way that this would be leaking memory is if these other controls are going to outlive the main window by a long period of time.  That sounds unlikely, and so having the main window attach a handler to those other controls with a reference to itself isn't going to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using  [github.com/shiftkey/Reactive.EventAggregator](http://github.com/shiftkey/Reactive.EventAggregator) 
as I already use Reactive in my program and it is quite simple

In MainWindow I have

```
using Reactive.EventAggregator;
MyEventAggregator.MessageAggregator = new EventAggregator();
MyEventAggregator.MessageAggregator.GetEvent<MessageEvent>().Subscribe(se =>
myMessageControl.Add(se)
);
```

Then there is a UserControl that has a ListBox LB

```
using Reactive.EventAggregator;
public partial class MessageControl : UserControl
{
    public MessageControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LB.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = this.MessageCollection });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MessageEvent> MessageCollection = new ObservableCollection<MessageEvent>();

    public void Add(MessageEvent m)
    {
        MessageCollection.Add(m);
    }
}

public class MyEventAggregator
{
    public static EventAggregator MessageAggregator { get; set; }
    public static void PostMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageAggregator.Publish(new MessageEvent(message));
    }
}
```

From anywhere in program I can use

```
MyEventAggregator.PostMessage("This message appears in MessageControl's Listbox");
```

It can be even simplified but I want the MessageEvent to hold more than just a string in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Prism provides you with an `EventAggregator` and takes care of managing the object. Using the aggregator you only publish and subscribe for events. If you need to pass some data you can publish them with the event.

```
this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish(myCustomData);
```

And when subscribing for the event you also can include a handler to process the data.

```
this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>).Subscribe(this.HandleMyCustomData);
```

With handler like that:

```
private void HandleMyCustomData(MyCustomData data) { }
```

Although it's still event based the solution is much more elegant than using classic events and handlers.

Under this link you can find much more thorough explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

Comment: Even though is seems simple I would like to try avoiding adding Prism to my solution just to have a log.

Comment: Fair enough. Still it might be a useful clue for anyone who is at the stage of planning rather than implementing.

Comment: @Daniel You can write your own simple EventAggregator quite easily. You can even look around the Internet to find an existing one without full Prism behind it.

Comment: I am trying to implement https://github.com/shiftkey/Reactive.EventAggregator but how I see it I need global object eventAggregator which needs to be accessible from all classes. This seems the same as if I called MainWindow.LogCollection.Add

Comment: Using above mentioned: If I understood I make `public static EventAggregator eventAggregator` and use it to publish and subscribe. It works and looks simple. Is that how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Prism EventAggregator is very nice for this sort of thing.

But if you don't want to sip the Prism Kool-Aid another approach that may work is for your MainWindow to register a custom TraceListener and have your other code use Trace methods to populate the log.  The MainWindow TraceListener can then do whatever you want with the Trace data.